# Getting all available category, subcategory list in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category, list-view

I want the replacement of the following code or similar to this code to get all category and subcategory in Magento 2.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

any help will be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 – Create you new Extension for our case in folder

**app/code/Ibnab/CategoriesSide**

and inside etc folder declare you etc declare `module.xml` and `di.xml` with content :
module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ibnab_CategoriesSide" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

 di.xml :
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Ibnab\CategoriesSide\Block\CategorisCollection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="deleteorderAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="context" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context</item>
                <item name="helper" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category</item>
                <item name="flatstate" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State</item>
               <item name="menu" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Note -** Here the dependency is for inject the class  `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category` for getting all categories of current store (And OR ) get the top menu html for the complete collection you need inject `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`  ,
2 -  the injection is for our data source the block
Ibnab\CategoriesSide\Block\CategorisCollection create and put the code :

```
<?php
namespace Ibnab\CategoriesSide\Block;
class CategorisCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $_categoryHelper;
     protected $categoryFlatConfig;
     protected $topMenu;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Return categories helper
     */   
    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }
    /**
     * Return top menu html
     * getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
     * example getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', 0)
     */   
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->topMenu->getHtml();
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current store categories
     *
     * @param bool|string $sorted
     * @param bool $asCollection
     * @param bool $toLoad
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Collection|array
     */    
   public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve child store categories
     *
     */ 
    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
           if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
                $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            } else {
                $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
            }
            return $subcategories;
    }
}
```

**Note –** The more important here is  getStoreCategories and getChildCategories($category)
  , it  get you the data collection tree from helper , and getHtml()
 is return the complete collection is more quick for correct the html
3 - ok now create you template inside `view/frontend/template/storecategories.phtml` with content :

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($categories as $category):
     if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php  
if($childrenCategories = $this->getChildCategories($category)):
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory):
     if (!$childrenCategory->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childrenCategory) ?>"><?php echo $childrenCategory->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
<?php
endif;
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
<h1>OR Just</h1>
<?php echo $this->getHtml() ?>
```

[For more detail see here.](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page)

enter preformatted text here

Comment: Thanks for you answer .
I want only category list that I got from Block.

Comment: I need one more help 
link goes here:

https://developerview.wordpress.com/2015/07/23/category-list-for-custom-magento-system-configuraion-section/

above for magento 2

Comment: Why is this simple task so complex? @MagentoCommunity

Comment: @StevieG if you have simple code then please post here

Comment: @Arunendra See answer below

Comment: I have used the above plugin, how to show the category images in home page, after clearing the cache, no images are shown if the category has images also

Comment: @stephen I know right..! 
Confused by the inclusion of 'Topmenu'? Also a little hard to follow the English here sorry!

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
 $catId =2;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);           
        $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
        ?>
        <ul >
            <li> <span> All Categories </span> </li>
            <?php
            foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
                if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {

                    $subcat_url = $subcat->getUrl();
                    $subcat_img = "";
                    $placeholder_img = "/media/placeholder.png";
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                            <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: obligatory comment that using ObjectManager technically works but is not recommended - please [see details](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly).

Answer (score 4):

**Magento 2.2.3**

### **Get all Subcategories base on current category.**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category    


    $catId =$category->getId();        
    $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);           
    $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
    ?>
    <ul >
        <?php
        foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {

                $subcat_url = $subcat->getUrl();
                $subcat_img = "";
                $placeholder_img = "/media/placeholder.png";
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                        <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
```