# Magento 2 : How can I get the sitemap in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.0.7, magento-2.2.1, sitemaps

How we create the **sitemap** page in Magento 2 like same we have in Magento 1?

```
http://example.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/
```

Comment: Talking About XML (sitemap.xml) / HTML Sitemap? https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/sitemap

Comment: I want the HTML site map same as in Magento1.x

Comment: To generate new sitemap for your site refer this may be possible you get help http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/12/magento-2-how-to-generate-sitemap-and.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento 2: By default not providing HTML Sitemap.

Can use Free Extension:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-seo-extension/

You have following options

- Use Plugin like http://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-sitemap-extension.html
- Create CMS Page & Put Links
- Make Custom Module to Generate HTML Sitemap Programmatically
- Use your Module/CMS Link to access that

**CMS Pages**: Can refer Magento 1 Article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020257/creating-a-magento-sitemap-page Then Convert it to Magento 2 will gonna Some What Helpfull for CMS Pages

**For Categories & Sub Categories**: [Getting all available category, subcategory list in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110466/getting-all-available-category-subcategory-list-in-magento-2)

**For Categories Product's**: [Magento 2: get product collection using category id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96177/magento-2-get-product-collection-using-category-id)

Comment: $79 dollars at Mageworx. Surprised there isn't a free version yet. Sitemap is pretty vital SEO wise.

Comment: Yup not by default. So choose from options which you prefer

Comment: Magento provide sitemap option. pls check: https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-sitemap-in-magento-2-0.html

Comment: this will also help: https://magenticians.com/create-magento-2-sitemap/

Answer (score 10):

As of Magento version 2.1.8, the sitemap functionality is included in the admin by default.

- Define sitemap location: **Marketing > SEO & Search > Site Map**. You can also manually generate the sitemap file from here.
- Configure cron settings: **Stores> Configuration > Catalog > XML Sitemap**

Here are instructions for [setting up recurring cron jobs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html). Just like Magento 1.x, the system's cron calls the Magento cron script, which schedules jobs.

Comment: This should be the correct one, installing third party mods should be a last resort for something already built in. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

> Magento 2 doesn't have html sitemap url for category and products like
>   in magento 1.xx . For this, you can create a CMS page like 'sitemap/'
>   and call a phtml file

which will include the custom code to call all category

In cms page, call this:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::sitemap.phtml" name="customsitemap"}}
```

then in phtml, call this:

```
<?php 
$objectManagerr = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManagerr->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categoryy = $categoryFactory->create()   
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
//->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',1)
//->addAttributeToFilter('is_anchor',1);
$excludedCategory = array(0);

?>

<ul class="sitelist">
<?php foreach ($categoryy as $cc): ?>
    <?php if(!in_array($cc->getId(), $excludedCategory)):?>
        <div class = "sitemap-list" style="float:left;">
        <?php if ($cc->getLevel()==2):?>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="<?php echo $cc->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $cc->getName(); ?></a></h3>
                <?php
                    if($cc->getChildren())
                    {
                        $sub = explode(",", $cc->getChildren());
                        $categoryFactorysub = $objectManagerr->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
                        $categoryysub = $categoryFactorysub->create()   
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                        $subcat=$categoryysub->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>$sub));

                        //$subcat->printlogquery(true);exit;
                        ?>
                            <ul style="margin-left:15px;"> 
                        <?php foreach ($subcat as $subcategories){ ?>
                            <?php if ($subcategories->getLevel()==3):?>
                                <div class = "sitemap-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <?php if($subcategories->getImageUrl()): ?>
                                        <div class="mega-menu-ad">
                                            <img src="<?php echo ($subcategories->getImageUrl()); ?>" width="25" height="25" />
                                        </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <a href="<?php echo $subcategories->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $subcategories->getName(); ?></a>
                                        <?php
                                            if($subcategories->getChildren())
                                            {
                                                $subSubCat = explode(",", $subcategories->getChildren());
                                                $subsubCatFactory = $objectManagerr->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
                                                $subSubCatCollection = $subsubCatFactory->create()
                                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                                                $subSubCollection=$subSubCatCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>$subSubCat));
                                                ?>
                                                    <ul style="margin-left:20px;">
                                                <?php foreach ($subSubCollection as $subSubcategories){ ?>
                                                        <div class = "sitemap-list">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <?php if($subSubcategories->getImageUrl()): ?>
                                                                <div class="mega-menu-ad">
                                                                    <img src="<?php echo ($subSubcategories->getImageUrl()); ?>" width="25" height="25" />
                                                                </div>
                                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                                <a href="<?php echo $subSubcategories->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $subSubcategories->getName()?></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </div>
                                                <?php } ?> 
                                                    </ul>
                                        <?php   } ?>

                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                <?php   } ?>

            </li>
        <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

This way you can easily create a sitemap URL in the Magento 2.

Comment: Hi, i want to create my own html sitemap can you please help me.. how to use this code. @Riddhish Bhayani

Answer (score 2):

You can develop your module which will extend the default Magento module `module-sitemap`.

You can based on the `Sitemap` model with the `\Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap::generateXml` and `_initSitemapItems` methods.

2 approaches :

1. Create a new `FO controller` and manage the display with `template/layout` etc.
2. Generate a static file in HTML which will be served by `Webserver` to a custom URL.

It will not be very difficult.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Free Magento 2 Dynamic HTML Sitemap extension :

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-dynamic-html-sitemap-extension.html

Easy to install and dynamic page with no time, Follow the link above and download.

You can easily customize an URL key for the sitemap and sitemap page.

All the featured are on the plugin website ;

Happy Coding