# Show list of all categories with links, on all pages

Tags: magento2, category

There's a few posts regarding how to get a list of categories in Magento 2, but they all seem to require getting the current category.

I'm looking for a php solution to show a list of all categories on every page, so I need a solution that doesn't require checking the current category. My goal is to create a custom navigation menu with 3 layers of sub-category depth.

Is there anyway I can get these lists with a foreach statement in a custom template block?

**EDIT:**

This is the error I am receiving with the answer:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "is_enable_attribute11" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "is_enable_attribute11" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.

Comment: Try below solution in another ticket: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110466/getting-all-available-category-subcategory-list-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Here i create category list, category show in list which is enable for listing **( Custom attribute into Category Form)**.

for enable and disable i create custom category attribute. and enable category show in list.

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName**

***InstallData***

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1', '<=')) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                    'is_enable_attribute11',
                        [
                            'type'     => 'int',
                            'label'    => 'Display Category in List',
                            'input'    => 'Boolean',
                            'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                            'visible'  => true,
                            'required' => false,
                            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                            'group' => 'General Information',

                        ]
                );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**InstallData.php** file run only one time when your module is installing first time.
**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\ui_component**

***category_form.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="is_enable_attribute11">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Display Category in List</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                        <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                        </item>  
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\Block**

***Categorylist.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Categorylist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_categoryNameFactory;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryNameFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryNameFactory = $categoryNameFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $collecionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getEnableCategory()
    {

        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('is_enable_attribute11',1)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        return $category;
    }

    public function getCategoryName($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryNameFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        return $category;
    }
}
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates**

***category.phtml***

```
<?php
$category = $block->getEnableCategory();
?>
<h1 align="center">Category  list</h1>
<div class="category-show-main">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <?php foreach($category as $categorydata) : ?>
        <?php
          $categoryid = $categorydata->getEntityId();
          $categoryFactory = $block->getCategoryName($categoryid);
          $categoryNameshow = $categoryFactory->getName();
          $categoryUrlShow = $categoryFactory->getUrl();
        ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide main-category-show-slide">
          <a class="category-link-show" href="<?php echo $categoryUrlShow; ?>" alt="<?php echo $categoryNameshow; ?>" title="<?php echo $categoryNameshow; ?>" >
            <div class="category-show-cmspage">
                <div class="category-slide">
                        <div class="category-name-show"><?php echo $categoryNameshow; ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="blank-div">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
     <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function  () {    
    require(['jquery', 'swiperjs'], function($,swiperjs) {
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            var swiper = new swiperjs('.swiper-container', {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                  spaceBetween: 15,
                  loop: false,
                  pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                    clickable: true,
                  },
                  navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                  },
              });
        });
    });
})();
// ]]></script>
```

Add this in your layout file where you want to show category list. And if you want to show all pages add this into **default.xml**

```
<block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Categorylist" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::category.phtml"/>
```

and for slider i used **swiper** so add this js file also in your layout

```
<head>
     <css src="VendoreName_ModuleName::css/swiper.min.css"/> 
</head>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I will test this code and let you know my results!

Comment: Do I need to create a routers.xml file and controller for this module?

Comment: Yes you need to create route.xml for show your category list on frontend layout page

Comment: Let me inform above solution is works for you ??

Comment: I definitely will, okay so I don't need a /controller/index/index.php/ file as well? Sorry I am new to modules, Magento and MVVM.

Comment: So it's means above solution is works for you it's good new. So now you can accept answer and vote up my answer. Because it's helpful for other users.

Comment: I have not confirmed it works yet because I am still learning how to install a custom module and need to test. I will answer the question once I confirmed, thanks again.

Comment: Let me inform me once you did it ? And if you have any Query you can ask here.

Comment: I believe I have installed the module correctly, I am also running the commands cache:flush and setup:upgrade when I make changes. But I am receiving an error, see my post edit.

Comment: Looking at the code, I am not sure if this module is supposed to create a product attribute in the CMS with the attribute code "is_enable_attribute11", but it did not.

Comment: This attribute is already created that's why this error comes. Check this in category form. Rename attribute in InstallData.php and category_form.xml  and remove 
modul name entry from setup_module table.then try again

Comment: I tried renaming the attribute from "is_enable_attribute11" to "category_module_attribute", then I cleared cache and ran setup:upgrade. I get the same error with my new name:    The "category_module_attribute" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.

Comment: ^ I changed the attribute name in InstallData.php, category_form.xml and Categorylist.php

Comment: Now error still come you need to remove this custom attribute and try again to install with a new name.

Comment: Hello @Msquare Please help me this problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304829/magento-2-showing-category-in-homepage-with-products-using-enable-disable-attrib?noredirect=1#comment439379_304829