# Magento 2 showing category in homepage with products using enable/disable attributes

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute, home-page

How to get the all custom category on homepage with products.

I want to create these types, Please check screens-short:- **https://prnt.sc/r5b2q5**

Showing this category:-

[image]

Above category showing this position:-

[image]

I want to custom getting all categories above the top seller products.
and I want to the category showing homepage enable/disable attributes

> category attributes are yes so category showing on the homepage with products.

Please help me

Thanks.

Comment: try this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303807/show-list-of-all-categories-with-links-on-all-pages/303828#303828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create following files for that.
Step 1: registration.php and etc/module.xml

Step 2:Solwin\Module2\Setup\InstallData.php
<?php
namespace Solwin\Module2\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'is_enable_attribute11',
                [
                    'type'     => 'int',
                    'label'    => 'Display Category in List',
                    'input'    => 'Boolean',
                    'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'visible'  => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',

                ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}

Step 3: Solwin/Module2/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="is_enable_attribute11">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Display Category in List</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                        <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                        </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>

Step 4:Solwin\Module2\Block\Categorylist.php
<?php

namespace Solwin\Module2\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Categorylist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_categoryNameFactory;

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryNameFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryNameFactory = $categoryNameFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $collecionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getEnableCategory()
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_enable_attribute11',1)
        ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        return $category;
    }

    public function getCategoryName($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryNameFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        return $category;
    }

    public function getProductCollection($categoryId)
    {
      $category = $this->_categoryNameFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
       return $category;
    }
}


Step 5:Solwin/Module2/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="Solwin\Module2\Block\Categorylist" template="Solwin_Module2::category.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Step 6:Solwin/Module2/view/frontend/templates/category.phtml

<?php
$category = $block->getEnableCategory();

$imageBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
?>
<h1 align="center">Category  list</h1>
<div class="tab">
  <?php foreach($category as $categorydata) : ?>
    <?php
      $categoryid = $categorydata->getEntityId();
      $categoryFactory = $block->getCategoryName($categoryid);
      $categoryNameshow = $categoryFactory->getName();
      $categoryUrlShow = $categoryFactory->getUrl();
    ?>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,'<?php echo $categoryNameshow; ?>')"><?php echo $categoryNameshow; ?></button>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php foreach($category as $categorydata) {
  $categoryFactory = $block->getCategoryName($categorydata->getEntityId());
  $categoryNameshow = $categoryFactory->getName();
  ?>
  <div id="<?php echo $categoryNameshow; ?>" class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="category-products">
      <?php
      $prodcollection = $block->getProductCollection($categorydata->getEntityId());
      foreach($prodcollection as $product) {
        $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'category_page_list');
          ?>
          <li class="productli">
              <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                  <?php echo $product->getName();?>
                  <?php echo $productImage->toHtml();  ?>
              </a>
          </li>
          <?php
      } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
<script>

var mybtn = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0];
mybtn.click();

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
<style>
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.productli {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid#ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes , this useful but only category show on homepage but my questions is category with products show..

Comment: Hi Mohit! I have updated the answer as per your requirement.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer and i wiil check the your code .

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides the widget feature and you can use that to show category products on specified area. for reference see attached images[image]

[image]

Comment: but i want to custom module